# opencv homography of nonlineer papers

Tags: opencv, image-processing, edge-detection, homography

I want to get the homography matrix for images whose edges are not linear. I have a solution for linear edges, but I want to rectify cases of non-linear edges.

I can detect edges and corners of image with code, but need to construct lines that are parallel to the top and bottom edges of an image.

I can do [this correction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8jTu.jpg), but my expected result image is a [full linear correction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNKGG.jpg)

Comment: Corrected grammar, rhetoric, and spelling.

Comment: Thank you, sorry for my English 